# Djnago - oracle DB - int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Tags: python-3.x, django, oracle, django-migrations

I configured **Django 2.0.2** with Oracle DB. **python 3.8**, **cx_Oracle 5.3** and **oracle instant client 19**. I am not able to run **python manage.py migarte**. While run migrate, we getting Error like

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

So help me with to configure a Django project with Oracle DB.

Comment: Can you should the migration file that causing exception?

Comment: not able to catch your point

Comment: migration file not yet created. before creating the file, It's shown me the error

Comment: Are you sure? I'm asking because `migrate` is "migrating" already existing migrations, where `makemigrations` creating them.

Comment: initail step. while running makemigartion, it shows me no changes detected. so I run migrate. but migarte show me int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list' error

Comment: Can you show then your models?

Comment: I did not create any new model. I want the default setup.

Comment: install django. makemiration. migarte. not yet added any new model.

Comment: Ok, so something with project initialization. Could you add full traceback of this error?

Comment: I will share it later. Please give me a django with oracle configuration setup best documentation

Comment: [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/#oracle-notes) you can read about recomended setup. Also, [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29759) looks like a related issue.